# Python Converts integer into a bit number of specific length, fast

Tags: python, integer, bit, typeconverter

I am trying to delta compress a list of pixels and store them in a binary file. I have managed to do this however the method I found takes ~4 minutes a frame.

```
def getByte_List(self):
    values = BitArray("")
    for I in range(len(self.delta_values)):
        temp = Bits(int= self.delta_values[I], length=self.num_bits_pixel)
        values.append(temp)
    ##start_time = time.time()
    bit_stream = pack("uint:16, uint:5, bits", self.intial_value, self.num_bits_pixel, values)
    ##end_time = time.time()
    ##print(end_time - start_time)

    # Make sure that the list of bits contains a multiple of 8 values
    if (len(bit_stream) % 8):
        bit_stream.append(Bits(uint=0, length = (8-(len(bit_stream) % 8))))                           #####Append? On a pack? (Only work on bitarray? bit_stream = BitArray("")

    # Create a list of unsigned integer values to represent each byte in the stream
    fmt = (len(bit_stream)/8) * ["uint:8"]
    return bit_stream.unpack(fmt)
```

This is my code. I take the initial value, the number of bits per pixel and the delta values and convert them into bits. I then byte align and take the integer representation of the bytes and use it elsewhere. The problem areas are where I convert each delta value to bits(3min) and where I pack(1min). Is it possible to do what I am doing faster or another way to pack them straight into integers representing bytes.

Comment: For this kind of manipulation, you most certainly want to use a lower-level language, or the excellent  [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/). Straight python is not really suitable for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a quick Google of the classes you're instantiating, it looks like you're using the `bitstring` module. This is written in pure Python, so it's not a big surprise that it's pretty slow. You might look at one or more of the following:

- `struct` - a module that comes with Python that will let you pack and unpack C structures into constituent values
- `bytearray` - a built-in type that lets you accumulate, well, an array of bytes, and has both list-like and string-like operations
- `bin(x)`, `int(x, 2)` - conversion of numbers to a binary representation as a string, and back - string manipulations can sometimes be a reasonably efficient way to do this
- `bitarray` - native (C) module for bit manipulation, looks like it has similar functionality to `bitstring` but should be much faster. Available [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) in form suitable for compiling on Linux or [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#bitarray) pre-compiled for Windows.
- `numpy` - fast manipulation of arrays of various types including single bytes. Kind of the go-to module for this sort of thing, frankly. http://www.numpy.org/